# How to create/trigger event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How do i create and pass the event to event handler?

Basically i want to fire an event called key down on focus of text input box how do i do that?

Comment: Perhaps firing `keydown` isn't what you want - it won't cause a letter to be inserted.

Comment: there are already onkeydown, change events. What exact is your scenario?

Comment: @Box9 & @nEEbz you can look at answer given by me which fits into my requirement, thank you for support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i found which meets my requirement using Jquery.

```
$('#inputText').focus(function() {
         $('#inputText').trigger({type:'keyup',keyCode:'40'});
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably [blog entry](http://jehiah.cz/a/firing-javascript-events-properly) should help you.

```
<input type="text" onchange="alert('i was clicked')" id="test">
<script>
    document.getElementById("test").onchange()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you actually want to trigger the event programmatically:

```
function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
   (el.fireEvent('on' + etype));
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}
```